# Find out the number of female employees in the organisation? Without using Group By

Tags: sql

How to find it...

Any one explain

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: No.. write your syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any example data would be helpful.
Otherwise, here is example query:

```
select count(*) from workers where gender = 'f';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: Thank you so much guyzzz

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
   select count(*) from emp where gender='female';
```

Considering the table to be emp